# Is it possible for some results to be "more" statistically significant than others provided they both have p values less than 0.05?

Tags: statistics

Say you have two sets, and the mean of one is higher than the other. A two-sample t test yields a result of p = 0.01, indicating a significant difference in means. Another pair of sets also have different means, but a two-sample t test yields a result of p = 0.04. Would it be correct to call the results from the first pair of sets "more" statistically significant since the p value is lower?

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be correct to call the results from the first pair of sets "more" statistically significant since the p value is lower?

Yes, absolutely right. The p-value represents a measure of significance's level of the test

As a Statistical practice

- if $p<5\%$ the test is significant
- if $p<1\%$ the test is Highly significant
- if $p>5\%$ the test is not significant